# Continuity in date

Tags: r

I have survey data where the employee has to enter his data for following questions continuously. I'm trying to check if they have filled the data continuously or not by using R.

The data is as follows:

```
EmployeeID <- c(101,101,101,102,102,102,102,104,104)

Created <- c(2020-06-19,2020-06-20,2020-06-21,2020-06-24,2020-06-25,2020-06-28,2020-06-28,2020-06-23,2020-06-24)

Updated <- c(2020-06-19,2020-06-20,2020-06-21,2020-06-24,2020-06-25,2020-06-28,2020-06-28,2020-06-23,2020-06-24)

happy <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")

active <- c("false", "false", " "," ", "false", "True"," ", "false", "false")

sad <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")

energitic <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")

df <- data.frame(EmployeeID, Created, Updated, happy, active, sad, energitic)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: I have added expected output, I want to know no of id who have entered data continuously and  no of id who have not entered data continuously by date wise

Comment: I guess your input data for 'Created', 'Updated' needs to be string or Date

Comment: What have you tried already to accomplish this and where are you having problems?

Comment: I noticed that I can figure it out through data column , but struck how to implement it to get my desired result

Comment: In your data, is `Created` an actual `Date` object, or as you have it here, the result of the mathematic expression 2020 minus 6 minus 19? (Your sample data is not representative, I suspect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(EmployeeID) %>%
  summarize(
    continuous = all(do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(Created)), by = "day")) %in% Created),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   EmployeeID continuous
#        <dbl> <lgl>     
# 1        101 TRUE      
# 2        102 FALSE     
# 3        104 TRUE
```

---

BTW, your sample data is not representative of what you're suggesting. `2020-06-19` is not a date, it is an expression that evaluates to `1995`. I updated my answer above to account for them being real `Date` objects.

Here's the updated data:

```r
df <- local({
  EmployeeID <- c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 104, 104)
  Created <- c("2020-06-19", "2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24")
  Updated <- c("2020-06-19", "2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24")
  happy <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
  active <- c("false", "false", " "," ", "false", "True"," ", "false", "false")
  sad <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
  energitic <- c("True", "false", "false"," ", "false", "True","false", "True", "false")
  data.frame(EmployeeID, Created, Updated, happy, active, sad, energitic)
})
df[,c("Created","Updated")] <- lapply(df[,c("Created","Updated")], as.Date)
```

Comment: My question is if they entered the data day wide continuously for instance employee 101 and 104 have entered the data continuously where as 102 has not entered the data on 2020-06-22, 2020-06-23 .

Comment: Thank you It worked for me . and one more I want to know the total of True and False for this .can you please guide me on this , for instance true=2 and false =1

Comment: Total? `%>% count(continuous)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check for continuity by taking the difference of consecutive `Created` date values and see if `all` of them have the difference of 1.

This can be done with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(EmployeeID) %>%
  summarise(Result = all(diff(Created) == 1))

# EmployeeID Result
#       <dbl> <lgl> 
#1        101 TRUE  
#2        102 FALSE 
#3        104 TRUE
```

Base R :

```
aggregate(Created~EmployeeID, df, function(x) all(diff(x) == 1))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Result = all(diff(Created) == 1)), EmployeeID]
```